# Apply comparaison in a board even if the lines do not follow each other

Tags: vba, excel

## # Good morning ! #

Here is my board :

[image]

And my job is to compare each line. There are no problems when the C colomn is different.
But when they are same (like row 15 and 16), I need to compare colomn D, after E....

This is my code for that :

```
Sub Macro2()

If Range("C15") = Range("C16") Then


        'call spread

        If Range("D15") = Range("D16") Then    'Date
            If Range("E15") = Range("E16") Then    'Call / put
                     Range("K2") = "call/put spread"    'nom de la strat
            End If
        End If



        'risk reversal

        If Range("D15") = Range("D16") Then    'Date
            If Range("E15") <> Range("E16") Then    'Call / put
                If Range("F15") <> Range("F16") Then    'prix
                    If Range("G15") = Range("G16") Then    'heure
                             Range("K2") = "risk reversal"    'nom de la strat
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If



        'Synthetics

        If Range("D15") = Range("D16") Then    'Date
            If Range("E15") <> Range("E16") Then    'Call / put
                If Range("F15") = Range("F16") Then    'prix
                    If Range("G15") = Range("G16") Then    'heure
                             Range("K2") = "Synthetics"    'nom de la strat
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If


        'calls/puts calandar

        If Range("D15") <> Range("D16") Then    'Date
            If Range("E15") = Range("E16") Then    'Call / put
                If Range("F15") <> Range("F16") Then    'prix
                    If Range("G15") = Range("G16") Then    'heure
                             Range("K2") = "calls/puts calandar"    'nom de la strat
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If


    End If
End sub
```

It works well, but how do it when rows dont follow each other ?

Comment: `application.worksheetfunction.match` to find them, then `offset`

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Can you explain little bit more pls ? I mean, how this fonction work and when it match 2 same name, how i say to compare the same rows but next colomn ?

Comment: Use the MSDN page for it, the help, put something together from that https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835873.aspx

Comment: yeah sorry to do the idiot but I am still lost...

Comment: so  you gave it 4minutes?

Comment: No, I read, I just dont understand this fonction even with the exemple